# jquery onscroll hasClass propery not working

Tags: jquery, html

In my template, I tracked the `up scroll` and `down scroll`.

On upscroll I added some `class names` to `h2`.  In `Downscroll` if the `h2` has the class name I did some tasks.

In `Downscroll` I used the `hasClass` Property. But it is not get the dynamic added `class names`.

This is the script I used

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (st > lastScrollTop){ //down scroll

                $(".rightclassname h2").each(function(){
                    var moveright = $(this).offset().top 
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > moveright && !$(this).hasClass('reached')) {
                        $(this).addClass('reached');
                        console.log(moveright);
                    }
                })

                $(".leftclassname h2").each(function(){
                    var moveleft = $(this).offset().top ;
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > moveleft && !$(this).hasClass('reached'))
                    { 
                        console.log('Moveleft');
                        $(this).addClass('reached');
                    }
                })
        }
        else { //Up scroll

                $(".rightclassname h2").each(function(){
                    var moveright = $(this).offset().top   ;

                    if($(window).scrollTop() < moveright && !$(this).hasClass('reached')) {
                        $(this).addClass('reached');
                        console.log('right up ');
                    }
                })


                $(".leftclassname h2").each(function(){
                    var moveleft = $(this).offset().top  ;
                    if($(window).scrollTop() < moveleft && !$(this).hasClass('reached'))
                    { 
                        $(this).addClass('reached');
                        console.log('leftup');
                    }
                })
        }
        lastScrollTop = st; 
    })
})
```

This code is working fine in `down scroll`. But in `up scroll` the `hasclass` property not tracked the dynamic added class `reached`. So it is not working fine.

Please help me how to track the `hasClass`property here.

****Please refer this fiddle [Refer the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/38bv4fnf/2/)**

While `downscroll`, by cross the corresponding heading th etext displayed correctly. By `upscroll` it is not working.**

Comment: Please refer my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/38bv4fnf/2/. 

While downscroll, by cross the corresponding heading th etext displayed correctly. By upscroll it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have formatted 'each' like 'map', I do this all the time on accident... but I think its supposed to be like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```